# How can I add icons in Magento Homepage header?

Tags: header, home, magento-1.9.2.1

May i know how to add icons in header ?
[image]

Comment: It completely depends upon your theme and without knowing the code which is working inside that, it will be very hard for someone here to answer this.

Comment: Thank You For Reply ..just tel me how to add that ? what is the code ? normally

Comment: You can try to achieve something via CSS. There are many resources out there for this. This is not Magento specific unless you want it to be configurable via admin.

Comment: ok...may i know one thing ? is there seprate code for home page and otherpages ?i add what i want in header but its not showing in home page ?

Comment: Generally, it's header which is present throughout the whole site. But, as you are using some custom theme, it might be possible that you are having different headers for different pages. If that's the case, then you have a complex theme at your hand and the developers of that theme would be having some pointers about how you can achieve this.

Comment: thank you....i will try my level best ..i have to search for homepage code ..

Comment: Homepage code is generally a CMS page with URL key home. But these links might be in some static block, or may be inside your header.phtml file in 'app/design/<PACKAGE>/<THEME>/template/page/html' location. Try enabling template hints from admin, they will tell you the exact location of those links if they are coming from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Add your icons in file `app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\template\page\html\header.phtml`

Like this way before function `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>`

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="" ><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/fam_book_open.png"') ?>" alt="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a Toplink in your website header, create a custom module and then follow this:

**Method#1 Basic link using layout XML**

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="whatsapp-link" before="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact us on Whatsapp</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">some-path-url-string</argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-whatsapp</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                    <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>       
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

By just using this file, you will be able to create a custom top link, and with the added class you can style it in you css/less files.

**Method#2 Using Template phtml file** Sometimes there are requirements when you need more control over newly added toplinks, or add image or write your own html. For adding a custom toplink using a template, follow this way.

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="whatsapp-link" template="Namespace_Modulename::whatsappLink.phtml">
            </block>       
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And then add the template phtml file defined in xml above in your code as follow.

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/whatsappLink.phtml
<li class="link whatsapp-link">
    <a href="some-path-url-string" title="Connect via Whatsapp" target="_blank">
        <img class="whatsapp-img" src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Namespace_Modulename::images/WhatsApp_logo.png'); ?>' alt="Whatsapp Image">
        <span class="whatsapp-label">Connect via Whatsapp</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Using this way, I added my icon with toplink and I can play with it as per requirement.