# Magento 2 add link and icon in header

Tags: magento2, headerlink

So I wanna add a Link with Icon and the text that says "Contact Us" beside "Mina sidor" in the header. So when u click on Contact Us u are directed to a different page with all contact information.

[image]

I have been adding this line of code to my Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml file and after that clearing the cache but nothing happens. I've been looking around but I doesn't seem to find where "Mina sidor" and "Varukorg" are made.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="new.link" after="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">New Link</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">newlink</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

- [How can I add icons in Magento Homepage header?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93098/how-can-i-add-icons-in-magento-homepage-header)
- [How to add or remove header.links in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138357/how-to-add-or-remove-header-links-in-magento2/138359)
- https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-link-in-header-links-and-top-links-in-magento-2/
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/How-to-add-Header-links-to-category-section/td-p/133946

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="header.panel">
        <block name="customblock" template="Vendor_Module::custom_file.phtml" after="-" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Now create a template file for this as mentioned in layout and write your code for Text, Link or Icon whatever you wish in the template file.

Answer (score 0):

To add a Toplink in your website header, create a custom module and then follow this:

**Method#1 Basic link using layout XML**

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="whatsapp-link" before="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact us on Whatsapp</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">some-path-url-string</argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-whatsapp</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                    <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>       
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

By just using this file, you will be able to create a custom top link, and with the added class you can style it in you css/less files.

**Method#2 Using Template phtml file** Sometimes there are requirements when you need more control over newly added toplinks, or add image or write your own html. For adding a custom toplink using a template, follow this way.

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="whatsapp-link" template="Namespace_Modulename::whatsappLink.phtml">
            </block>       
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And then add the template phtml file defined in xml above in your code as follow.

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/whatsappLink.phtml
<li class="link whatsapp-link">
    <a href="some-path-url-string" title="Connect via Whatsapp" target="_blank">
        <img class="whatsapp-img" src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Namespace_Modulename::images/WhatsApp_logo.png'); ?>' alt="Whatsapp Image">
        <span class="whatsapp-label">Connect via Whatsapp</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Using this way, I added my icon with toplink and I can play with it as per requirement.